# how can I get jquery.sIFR plugin to display sIFR-alternate text for print?

Tags: jquery, flash, sifr, print-style

I'm struggling with this. I've used the jquery sIFR plugin as opposed to sIFR it prevented conflicts with other jquery I am using on my pages.

It works fine in its prime function: replacing html text with Flash.

However, the .sIFR-alternate class is given an inline style of 'opacity: 0' which persists when flashblock is on. So alternate text does not appear. Neither does it appear when printng the page (yes I have included styles for sIFR-print).

I've tried replacing the opacity:0 inline style with display: none but this causes height issues with the output flash.

Any one else had this or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How does sIFR-proper conflict with jQuery? It shouldn't, really.

Comment: Sorry, incorrect terminology. The problem wasn't a code conflict but a timing issue with regards rendering. The site had some hidden content which would be displayed only after user-interaction. With sIFR proper the hidden flash text wouldn't render on show. I am no javascript pro but I have a decent understanding of jquery fundamentals, so I used jquery sIFR plugin to render stuff when called. Probably a long-winded way round!
Anyway, I solved the original issue by taking the inline opacity style out of the plugin .js file and adding the required styles to my screen & print .css files.